# I can't find a way to stop printing the csv file when it finds a certain character

Tags: c, csv

Title is pretty self explanatory, I wanted to know what's the best way to stop printing a csv file when it finds a certain character, for example I want to stop printing text when it finds an ";", here are my attempts:

```c
void testeperguntas(){
    FILE *in;

    char str[MAXCHARS];
    if ((in = fopen("../data/perguntas.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Erro: perguntas!");
    }
    if (in) {
        while (fscanf(in, "%s", str)!=EOF)
            printf("%s",str);
        fclose(in);
    }
}
```

and:

```c
void testeperguntas1(){

    char buf[400];

    FILE *in = fopen("../data/perguntas.txt", "r");


    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), in))
    {
        char *token;

        token = strtok(buf, ",");
        while (token!= NULL) {
            printf("%s", token);
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

both ways I can't find a way, I'd appreciate any help thx

Comment: The command is `break`

Comment: Ask yourself: what happens when fscanf returns 0? When does it do that? (Note that EOF is negative).

Comment: Are you expecting to find ';' before or after you have printed it?  If the ';' is in some string, do you want to print all the characters before the ';' in the string?  Please clarify exactly what you want to do.

Comment: are you familiar with the function: `strchr()`?

Comment: when a call to `fopen()` fails, output your error message to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  When outputting the error message, also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.  The `perror()` function performs both outputs to `stderr`.  When the call to `fopen()` fails, do not continue executing the code.  Rather, since this is an unrecoverable error, the next statement, after the call to `perror()` should be: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: regarding: `printf("%s", token);`  This will output the 'token' strings jammed right against each other.  Suggest either: `printf( "%s ", token );`  or `printf( "%s\n", token );`

Comment: regarding: `while (fscanf(in, "%s", str)!=EOF)`  it is (almost) always best to check for 'success' rather than 'not failure'.  Suggest:`while (fscanf(in, "%s", str) == 1 )`  Also, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer 'str[]' to avoid any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior.  Note: 1 less than the length of the input buffer because `%s` always appends a NUL byte to the input buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I can not find **break keyword** inside your loop

```
while (fscanf(in, "%s", str)!=EOF)
{
     printf("%s",str);
    if(strcmp(str,";")==0)
       break;

}
```

like this

Comment: thiis has the problem that the contents of `str[]` must be ';' followed by '\0'.  Suggest making use of `strchr()` and/or `strcspn()`